# Scaladoc: Do I really need to give the full path everytime I use a link?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, scaladoc

This screenshot summarizes my problem pretty well I think:

I want to link to an object/class/method/... in Scaladoc. Even when I have the package correctly importet (see: `import zoo.animals.Dog` in my example) IntelliJ does not correctly recognize the path to that object (marks it as red; non-clickable. This does not even work if that object I am referencing is in the same package!

[image: It doesn't work like that!]

Do I really have to write something like e.g. `@return a [[zoo.animals.Dog]]` everytime? This can get quite tedious when dealing with large projects with very deep package structures.
But then it works:

[image: It works like that!]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run the [scaladoc](https://docs.scala-lang.org/style/scaladoc.html) for the project (in IDE you can run it via Tools | "Generate Scaladoc" action) it will also generate the scaladoc without the link if you do not specify the fully qualified class name. So the full class name is required there.

Comment: That is a bit unfortunate. Well it is an answer though :)